# Object detection usage example layout

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to learn yolov3 and I cannot make this example work.

How do I insert the usage example at the top?

Where does this go?

> ```
> # Usage example: python3 object_detection_yolo.py --video=run.mp4 --device 'cpu'
> ```

Currently, it throws up a runtime error.

```
# This code is written at BigVision LLC. It is based on the OpenCV project. It is subject to the license terms in the LICENSE file found in this distribution and at http://opencv.org/license.html

# Usage example:  python3 object_detection_yolo.py --video=run.mp4 --device 'cpu'
#                 python3 object_detection_yolo.py --video=run.mp4 --device 'gpu'
#                 python3 object_detection_yolo.py --image=bird.jpg --device 'cpu'
#                 python3 object_detection_yolo.py --image=bird.jpg --device 'gpu'

import cv2 as cv
import argparse
import sys
import numpy as np
import os.path

# Initialize the parameters
confThreshold = 0.5  #Confidence threshold
nmsThreshold = 0.4   #Non-maximum suppression threshold
inpWidth = 416       #Width of network's input image
inpHeight = 416      #Height of network's input image


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Object Detection using YOLO in OPENCV')
parser.add_argument('--device', default='cpu', help="Device to perform inference on 'cpu' or 'gpu'.")
parser.add_argument('--image', help='Path to image file.')
parser.add_argument('--video', help='Path to video file.')
args = parser.parse_args()
        
# Load names of classes
classesFile = "coco.names"
classes = None
with open(classesFile, 'rt') as f:
    classes = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

# Give the configuration and weight files for the model and load the network using them.
modelConfiguration = "yolov3.cfg"
modelWeights = "yolov3.weights"

net = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration, modelWeights)

if(args.device == 'cpu'):
    net.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
    net.setPreferableTarget(cv.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)
    print('Using CPU device.')
elif(args.device == 'gpu'):
    net.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
    net.setPreferableTarget(cv.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)
    print('Using GPU device.')
```

Comment: What does the runtime error say?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).